# Read Security Audit Log static and dynamic filters using RFC

Tags: filter, abap, audit, saprfc, sap-basis

I am trying to read SAP Audit Log static and dynamic filters setting (sm19) using RFC connection.

For static filters i figured out they are stored in table `rsauprof`:

```
Field   Key Data Element    Type    Offset  Leng    Decimals    Check Table Text
PROFNAME    X   RSAUPNAME   CHAR    0   8   0       SecAudit: Audit profile name (of the configuration)
SLOTNO  X   RSAUSLOTNO  NUMC    8   4   0       Audit log: Number of the recording parameter (slot)
CURRPROF        RSAUCPROF   CHAR    12  8   0       Security Audit: Name of the current audit profile
CLASSES     RSAUCLASID  INT4    20  10  0       System audit log: Audit event classification indicator
SEVERITY        RSAUSEVERI  INT4    24  10  0       System audit log: Security levels
CLIENT      MANDT   CLNT    28  3   0   T000    Client
UNAME       XUBNAME CHAR    31  12  0   USR02   User Name in User Master Record
STATUS      RSAUSTATUS  CHAR    43  1   0       Audit activity indicator (slot)
CUNAME      RSAUCUNAME  CHAR    44  12  0   USR02   Security audit: SAP name of person who changed the profile
CDATE       RSAUCDATE   DATS    56  8   0       Security Audit: Date when the audit profile was changed
SELVAR      RSAUSELVAR  RAW 64  1   0       Security audit: determining selection variant
MSGVECT     RSAUMSGVEC  CHAR    65  1   0       Security audit: selection vector of audit events
```

Field of interests is `MSGVECT`, but I have problems to interpret that value because it looks like a bitvector.  How to convert that value into human-readable form?

For dynamic filters i didn't find any place to look for stored filter settings.

So the question is: how to read dynamic and static sap audit log filter settings from SAP?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `RSAU_CONFIG_SHOW` report which had been introduced with 750 and API it uses.

Method `GET_MSGVECT_FROM_ALV` of class `CL_SAL_CONFIG` is probably what you seek.